# Model filtering based on calculations

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I've some problem with getting some specific objects from my model.

My models looks like:

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    subscriber = models.ForeignKey(Subscriber, null=False, blank=False, default=None, editable=False)
    plan = models.ForeignKey(SubscriptionPlan, null=False, blank=False)
    active_from_date =models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)

class SubscriptionPlan(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, default=None)
    interval = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=30)
```

Now I want to get only these subscriptions which are valid, so I'm trying something like this:

```
valid = Subscription.objects.filter(valid_from_date__gte=(datetime.date.today()-timedelta(days=plan__interval)))
```

I've problem with access to value plan__interval. If I try to use constant value in this place, for example 10, then everything works properly.

Do you have any suggestions how can I use plan.interval value in filter calculations?

Comment: Was there an error generated?

Comment: I get runtime error: "global name 'plan__interval' is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in this :
[Filtering with calculations on fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model)

I still have a doubt since it is difficult to be consistent when adding INTEGERs to DATETIMEs, so you could add another `DatetimeField` to your `Subscription` and populate this value with the ending date according to the `plan` ForeignKey, in the `save(self, *args, **kwargs)` method of Subscription for example.

Comment: I known that I can add new filed, but it's redundant data from my point. This approach also can complicate other scenarios, for example changing plan to subscription.

Answer (score 1):

Raunak Agarwal's answer seems nice but try this :

valid = Subscription.objects.filter(active_from_date_*gte = datetime.date.today() - F('plan*_interval'))

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use annotate function to use foreign key in the filter

```
valid = Subscription.objects.annotate(plan_interval = Sum('plan__interval')).filter(valid_from_date__gte=(datetime.date.today()-timedelta(days=plan_interval)))
```

Comment: In my case isn't possible to have subscription without set plan. In this case I still get error: "global name 'plan__interval' is not defined"

Comment: Forgive me I read the question wrong. I have updated my answer. Take a look

Comment: Unfortunately after that I still get error "global name 'plan_interval' is not defined". Do you have any suggestions how can I resolve this problem?